# Sharing a Postgres (or other DBMS) transaction context between processes

Tags: database, postgresql, architecture, transactions

A common pattern in monolithic application design is to delegate business logic to a dedicated service, passing in an open transaction as, for example, a `javax.persistence.EntityTransaction` instance in Java, or an `sql.Transaction` in Go.

Go example:

```golang
// business.go

type BusinessLogicService interface {
    DoSomething(tx *sql.Transaction)
}

type businessLogicService struct {
}

func (s *BusinessLogicService) DoSomething(tx *sql.Transaction) {
    tx.ExecuteContext(.....)
}

func NewBusinessLogicService() {
    return &businessLogicService{}
}

// server.go

ctx := context.Background()
tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

bls := business.NewBusinessLogicService()
bls.DoSomething(tx)

tx.Commit()
```

Could the same effect be achieved in an architecture where each of these components are implemented in a different language/runtime?  In such an application, Postgres is responsible for doing the 'bookkeeping' in relation to the DB transaction.  It seems to me that it should be possible to pass a similar 'handle' for the transaction to another process to read its state and append operations.

For example the equivalent business logic is provided as a gRPC service with the following definition:

```proto
message TransactionInfo {
  string transaction_id = 1;
}

message DoSomethingRequest {
  TransactionInfo transaction_info = 1;
}
  
message DoSomethingResponse {
}

service BusinessLogicService {
  rpc DoSomething(DoSomethingRequest) returns (DoSomethingResponse)
}
```

The server process `BEGIN`s the transaction and passes a reference to this BusinessLogicService.

```golang
ctx := context.Background()
tx, err := db.BeginTx(ctx)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

conn, err := grpc.Dial(*serverAddr, opts...)
if err != nil {
  ...
}
defer conn.Close()
bls := pb.NewBusinessLogicClient()

/// SOMEHOW PASS THE TX OBJECT TO THE REMOTE SERVICE
txObj := &pb.TransactionInfo{....???????????.....}

result := bls.DoSomething(txObj)

tx.Commit()
```

Is this possible with Postgres or another DBMS?

Comment: Yes, that can be done in with Postgres and virtually every other rdbms also. However the specifics vary with the particular database and calling language whether it be Java,  Go, Python, or even (gasp) Fortran (yes that can be done).  However keep in mind that databases as highly data type specific and *matching your interface language to the database remains **your responsibility*** not the target database.

Comment: @Belayer sorry, I was unclear.  I meant they are implemented in **separate** runtimes/languages, perhaps communicating over some RPC protocol like gRPC.  I have updated the question to clarify.

Comment: @curious101 why would you do that? Are you not violating the database per service?